# ISNUMBER SEARCH / conditional formatting not working -__-

Tags: excel

I’m trying to make my A2 cell green when the text `"AZMA_Load"` is ANYWHERE in ANY CELL of column "I" on the same worksheet. I’m unable to add a picture for some reason, but cell "I6" contains `"dhahrhdjAZMA_Load"` and A2 DOESN’T turn green.

I’m infuriated.

In Edit Formatting Rule, my `"Format values where this formula is true"` formula is

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AZMA_Load",I6))
```

I know the last part of the formula is I6, but I’d like to search the entirety of Column I.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, this should be a functional conditional formatting rule for the A2 cell:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*AZMA_Load*",I:I,0))
```

You can't use SEARCH() because that works only for one cell. You also need to put asterisks before and after the AZMA_Load so excel knows to look not only for the exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Countif

```
=COUNTIF(I:I,"*AZMA_Load*")>0
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKED  thank you, kind souls. bless you both 

Comment: @McHenny No problem but on StackOverflow you say thanks by upvoting and selecting the answer that you find the most helpful. Commenting is optional.

Comment: my reputation isn’t high enough yet, but i’m posting again right and will DEFINITELY upvote when it is 